# torchaudio load audio with specific sampling rate

Tags: python-3.x, torchaudio

From documentation, https://pytorch.org/audio/stable/backend.html#torchaudio.backend.sox_io_backend.load it seems there is no parameter for loading audio with a fixed sampling rate which is important for training models.

How to load a pytorch audio tensor with a fixed sampling rate with torchaudio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resample with `torchaudio.functional.resample`

```
arr, org_sr = torchaudio.load('path')
arr = torchaudio.functional.resample(arr, orig_freq=org_sr, new_freq=new_sr)
```

Answer (score 2):

`Resample` can be used from transforms.

```
waveform, sample_rate = torchaudio.load('test.wav', normalize=True)
transform = transforms.Resample(sample_rate, sample_rate/10)
waveform = transform(waveform)
```